# Code Blocks is using 100% of CPU

Tags: 12.04, code-blocks

I'm using Code Blocks 10.05 on Ubuntu 12.04 and it's using 100% of the CPU with no project or files open.

Comment: Have you tried to `purge` (`sudo apt-get purge PACKAGE_NAME`) it and `install` (`sudo apt-get install package_name`) it again?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the program, which would mean this isn't on topic here.  I'm not marking it as such, yet, though.